# HTML/PHP DropDownList not being populated as desired, even though the data is in the DB

Tags: php, html

I am trying to use the following source to populate a DropDownList. The database has some table lines that are tagged as 'Option 1', 'Option 2', or 'Option 3' in column "alias_name". The other table lines, not tagged have a null in the "alias_name" column.  The resulting populated DropDownList shows all of the names, but only one out of all the lines has the " -- Option #" that should be concatenated to the name.  Separate DB queries prove that the data is in the database and the fact that one of the 14 lines of options is displayed properly is perplexing. Any ideas please?

```
<select name="event_names[]" multiple="multiple" size="6">
    <option value="all"<?php if(empty($event_names)||@in_array('all', $event_names))echo' selected';?>>ALL</option>

<?php
$m = Db::doQuery("SELECT name,alias_name FROM site_events WHERE name != '' GROUP BY name");
while ($n = $m->fetch_object()) {
    $e_alias = '';
    $e_name = $n->name;
    $e_alias = $n->alias_name;

    if($n->alias_name=='Option 1' || $n->alias_name=='Option 2' || $n- >alias_name=='Option 3') 
        {echo '<option value="'.$e_name.'"'.(@in_array($e_name, $event_names)?' selected':'').'>'.$e_name.' -- '.$e_alias.'</option>';}
    else  {echo '<option value="'.$e_name.'"'.(@in_array($e_name, $event_names)?' selected':'').'>'.$e_name.'</option>';}
} 
?>
</select>
```

Comment: During your loop can you echo out the contents of $e_alias (or $n->alias_name) to see if they are getting populated with the right values?  Also, have you looked at your HTML code to make sure your script isn't making any malformed HTML that may force the browser to not render the select box properly?

Comment: Problem solved, program was looking at a test database, which was not populated correctly.